# How to deserialize list of object json by NewtonSoft?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I Serialize below class  by Newtonsoft.Json but i can't Deserialize the same json by Newtonsoft.Json. How can i do that?

Json:

```
"{\"UserEvents\":[{\"id\":1214308,\"Date\":20150801000000,\"IsRead\":true}]}"
```

My Entities:

```
   public class UserEventLog {
    [JsonProperty("UserEvents")]
    public List<UserEvent> UserEvents { get; set; }
    public UserEventLog() {
        UserEvents = new List<UserEvent>();
    }
}


public class UserEvent {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long id{ get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public long Date{ get; set; }
      [JsonProperty("IsRead")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
}
```

My Deserializer is that :

```
  List<UserEventLog> convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserEventLog>>(user.ToString()) as List<UserEventLog>;
```

But **Error** is produced:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Error converting value `"{"UserEvents":[{"id":1214308,"Date":20150801000000,"IsRead":true}]}"` to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

How can i solve it? how can i Deserialize my List of object to UserEvents list?

Comment: your json-data does not contains list, it has one object

Comment: Your example string is not a list of `UserEventLog`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works in linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var user = "{\"UserEvents\":[{\"id\":1214308,\"Date\":20150801000000,\"IsRead\":true}]}";
    UserEventLog convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserEventLog>(user.ToString());
    convert.UserEvents.Count().Dump();
}

public class UserEventLog 
{
    [JsonProperty("UserEvents")]
    public List<UserEvent> UserEvents { get; set; }

    public UserEventLog() 
    {
        UserEvents = new List<UserEvent>();
    }
}


public class UserEvent 
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public long Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IsRead")]
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that you're trying to deserialize into list, but it is not an array of `UserEvents`

Comment: You don't need the `as UserEventLog` since [DeserializeObject<T>](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) returns T.